# Rake assets precompile failing

Tags: activerecord, rake

```
rails 3.2
```

In my database.yml, I have:

```
development: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mydb
  pool: 5
  username: 'mydb'
  password: 'mypwd'

staging:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost

sandbox:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
```

When I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=sandbox
RAILS_GROUPS=assets
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get the following:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
```

If I do:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging
RAILS_GROUPS=assets
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

It completes correctly. The staging and sandbox setting are the same. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Do you have `config/environments/sandbox.rb` defined?

Comment: Yes. It is an exact copy of staging.rb, and the only difference is the url (sandbox.mydomain.com)

Comment: Weird. Are you able to do `bundle exec rails c sandbox` and run a query like `User.count` (or whatever model you might have) and get a result?

Comment: I did not try it, because take precompile failed. But if I do everything as staging, then yes it works, yes this is weird

Comment: Yeah give a shot. The only thing that jumps to mind is that maybe the whitespace in your `config/database.yml` might be off around the `sandbox` block. Yaml is particular about spaces/tabs.

Comment: No go. I also made sure there are no tabs in the .yml file. I don't get it. I am going to try to re-ask this question, with more detail (include my environment file), even though i don't know what the environment would have to do with it